# Distributing SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-express

I have a windows service that hosts a WCF service which uses a sql server express database. I also have a setup project to intall the windows service. What are the steps I need to take to make sure SQL Server Express installs silently and that the database is setup correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article should have everything you need:

**Embedding SQL Server Express into Custom Applications** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: I checked that one out, but it not explain how to add it to the setup project.

Comment: It depends on the installer.  Generally speaking, it will be a "custom action" in the installer.